# Empty /mnt: store-backed instance launch from EBS-backed AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-ebs, amazon-ami

I have an EBS AMI which I want to publish in AWS Market Place.
The AMI was created with data in /mnt.
The snapshop includes both /dev/sda1 and /dev/sdb devices :
***Block Devices: /dev/sda1=snap-xxxxxx:8:true:standard, /dev/sdb=ephemeral0***

My problem is that when I create an instance-store root device instance (with ephemeral
device /dev/sdb) the /mnt folder is empty.

I know this is due to the fact that ephemeral disk are not copied for instance-store root device. So, what I would like to know is how can I create an AMI, that :

1. can generate all type of instances (from micro to X Large)
2. with principal storage device mounted as /mnt
3. no data loss in /mnt directory during launch of an instance

Thanks for replying,

Comment: micro instances don't have instance-store, so how are you planning on fulfilling #1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using instance-store for this volume, instead create a second EBS volume, attach it to your EC2 instance, and mount it under /mnt.

Then the AMI that is created will include that volume's data.  Any EC2 instances created from this AMI will have 2 volumes attached:  the primary boot volume, and a second storage volume.